# How to get cross-origin files into Google Drive via an API using client-side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

We are trying to get files from a URL over to Google Drive in a client-side web application.

The challenge is that Javascript has a Cross Origin Restriction when downloading files. The result is that if we give Javascript a list of URLs - it is unable to download the files to then put in Google Drive because the files are on a different website.

As an alternative, does Google Drive have an API reachable by Javascript that could be triggered to cause the Drive to pull down files from URLs? If so, how?

Note: This question is in contrast to other SO questions which ask how to get files *from* Google Drive. This question is focused on how to get cross-origin files *to* Google drive.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to achieve this would be to have the files' host server support CORS. I'm guessing that they don't and you have no control over them.

Drive does not have an upload from URL capability, so that's not an option.

Perhaps the most elegant solution would be for you to implement your own Drive proxy endpoint that accepts a source URL, fetches the content from that URL into a buffer, then uploads that buffer to Drive. Such a proxy would be fairly simple to write (< 50 lines of code) and could be hosted in a serverless environment such as Appengine, AWS Lambda, etc.